# Error en llamada json con jquery

Tags: jquery, json

En el siguiente código:

```
function genSearchBox (subject,target) {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: nivel()+'get/getSearchBox.php?jsoncallback=?',
       data: {subject:subject},
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType: 'json',
       success:
          function(jsonData) {
             $(target).html(jsonData);
          },
       complete:
          function() {
          },
       error:
          function() {
             alert('Content not loaded');
          }
    });
}
```

Siempre me sale el error: Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

En otras llamada similares, en el mismo programa, no da error.

¿Que puede ser?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente haces una llamada en la que se espera como respuesta un JSON pero obtienes un documento HTML o XML, posiblemente un error. Al intentar procesar el JSON el *parser* falla:

```js
const respuesta= '<html><body>Error 404</body></html>';
try {
  JSON.parse(respuesta);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: La rutina de respuesta (get/getSearchBox.php) devuelve "echo $_GET['jsoncallback']."(".json_encode($data).")"; "